# display the series and input digit count that if ...input n=900 then output will be 1 4 9 25 49 121 169 289 361 529 841 and count =3

Tags: c++, c

Help me out with my code or else a new one.  Here in this code I didn't wrote the digit count module yet. I tried it to print the squares of prime numbers i.e., less than the given n number, and I figure out the output with same numbers as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQACu.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num, i = 1, j, count, s = 1;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Num value To Print Prime Numbers between 1 and Num: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Prime Numbers upto %d :\n \n", num);
    while (i <= num)
    {
        if (s>num)
            break;
        count = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0) //checking whether num is dvisible by j
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 2)  //if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime
            s = i*i;
        printf("%d ", s);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    getch();
}
```

Output: `0 4 9 9 25 25 49 49 49 49 49 121 121 .......961`

Comment: `if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime`  No.. not unless it is exactly 2.

Comment: `if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime` it a check for even numbers not prime

Comment: `void main()`--> `int main()`

Comment: prime is when a number is only evenly divisible by 1 and itself  Also, some of the displayed numbers (for instance 25) are not prime numbers.

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  suggest enabling all warnings, re-compile, fix the warnings and re-post the code

Comment: @user3629249 none of them are prime numbers: they are the squares of prime numbers.

Comment: @WeatherVane, here is the direct statement from the code: '//if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime' which is an incorrect definition of 'prime number'  and the printf() statements clearly indicate the output is primes, not squares of primes

Comment: @user3629249 if it is prime, OP wants to output its square `s = i*i;`

Comment: when calling the function: scanf() (and family of functions) always check the returned code (not the parameters) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: I highly recommend you search StackOverflow for "c++ prime" for examples on calculating and checking for primes.  There are many for you to go through.

Comment: Also, use this program as a basis for learning to use a debugger.  With a debugger, you can `watch` or view the contents of variables as you execute each statement separately.  This is a lot faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for a response.

Answer (score 1):

here are some of the problems with the posted code.

1) main() must always have an 'int' return type

2) if the '-Wstrict-prototype warning is enabled, then the declaration of main must be:

```
int main( void )
```

3) the function clrscr() is not defined, suggest using:

```
system( "cls" );
```

4) the function getch() is not defined, suggest using:

```
getchar();
```

For human readability and ease of maintenace, suggest:

```
 only one variable declaration per line
 indent code via spaces, perhaps after each opening brace and before each closing brace
```

the definition of a 'prime' number, as stated in the code, is not correct.

the correct definition:

"A number is a prime number if it is evenly divisible only by 1 and itself"

Comment: OP's definition of a prime number is correct: it is divisible by two numbers: 1 and itself, as `count` commented is intended. It's not a very good algorithm, but that's not wrong. The functions `clrscr()` and `getch()` are from the MSVC non-standard library but `#include <conio.h>` is missing.

Comment: the header file conio.h is not portable, and should be avoided.  If the OP had enabled all the compiler warnings, they would have seen the problems and (hopefully)  fixed them.  IMO: an instructor should flunk any homework (which this obviously is) that does not cleanly compile.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that when `i` is not prime s will print out the previous value stored in it. You can either clear s or put it in braces in `if` condition

```
 while (i <= num)
{
    if (s>num)            //problem lies here
        break;
    count = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (i%j == 0) //checking whether num is dvisible by j
            count++;
    }
    if (count == 2)  //if num is divisible by 2 numbers,then it is prime
    {    
       s = i*i;
       printf("%d ", s);
    }
    //s = 0;       //or use this if you don't want to use braces which is a bad programming style
    i++;
}
```

**Also, 1 is not a prime number so your expectd output should start from 4**